# Magento1 Get the value and assign

Tags: magento-1.9

In my database I have `courses_id=4` and `number_of_courses=10`

I have a function in controller and write:

```
$id=4;
$courseCollection = Mage::getModel('course/courses')->getCollection();
$numberCourse = $courseCollection->getSelect()->where("courses_id='$id'")->columns('number_of_courses');
```

I want value **number_of_courses** from database for `$numberCourse`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$id=4;
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer');
$collection = Mage::getModel('course/courses')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('courses_id', $id);
foreach ($collection as $value) {
    echo $value['number_of_participants'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you devidas

Comment: Welcome Bro #happycoding